# Getting error while writing Jest test case for react component: "Cannot access 'initialState' before initialization "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am writing test cases using jest for one of my react component ProductDetailsForm.js where I encountered the below error.

```
FAIL  src/components/__tests__/ProductDetailsForm.test.js
Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'initialState' before initialization

  34 |
  35 | export default function reducer(state, action = {}) {
> 36 |     state = state || initialState;
     |                      ^
  37 |
  38 |     switch (action.type) {
  39 |         case AppDucksActionTypes.App_DUCKS_TOGGLE_SIDEBAR: {

  at reducer (src/redux/ducks/AppDucks.js:36:22)
  at node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:372:24
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at assertReducerShape (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:370:25)
  at combineReducers (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:435:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/rootReducer.js:20:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/store/createStore.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/services/HttpService.js:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/services/AppService.js:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/ducks/AppDucks.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/ProductDetailsForm.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/__tests__/ProductDetailsForm.test.js:3:1)
```

After a lot of digging through the code, I found out it might be because of something in the createStore.js (*where the redux store has been created*)

**How I came to the conclusion?**

***I commented out the import from createStore.js in HttpService.js (at line 2) and the test passed with no error***

Below are the code for different files for your reference.
The files are mentioned in sequence of how it is being used (like createStore.js is being imported in HttpService.js and HttpService.js imported in AppService.js and so on and so forth).

*createStore.js*

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import rootReducer from '../rootReducer';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const initialState = {};
const middleWares = [];

const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({

    }) : compose;

const composedEnhancers = composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middleWares)
);

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(
    pReducer,
    initialState,
    composedEnhancers
);

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export {
    store,
    persistor
};
```

*HttpService.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {store} from '../store/createStore';
import {showErrors} from '../ducks/AppDucks';

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    const {dispatch} = store;
    const errorHeader = response.headers['x-errors'];
    if (errorHeader) {
        const errors = JSON.parse(errorHeader);
        dispatch(showErrors(dispatch, errors));
    }
    return response;
});

export function get(uri, config = {}, responseType) {
    if (responseType) {
        config.responseType = responseType;
    }
    return axios.get(uri, config);
}

export function post(uri, data) {
    return axios.post(uri, data);
}

export default {
    get,
    post
}
```

*AppService.js*

```
import API_ROOT from './URI';
import HttpService from './HttpService';

export const fetchApiVersion = () => {
    let url = `${API_ROOT}/version`;
    let encodedURL = encodeURI(url);
    return HttpService
        .get(encodedURL)
        .then(res => res.data);
};
```

*AppDucks.js*

```
import keymirror from 'keymirror';
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
import { fetchApiVersion } from '../services/AppService';
import packageJson from '../../../package.json';

export const initialState = {
    ui: {
        sidebar: {
            showSidebar: true,
            expandedProductLineMap: {},
            selectedUploadType: ''
        }
    }
}

const AppDucksActionTypes = keymirror({
    App_DUCKS_GET_API_VERSION: null,
    App_DUCKS_TOGGLE_SIDEBAR: null
});

export const toggleSidebar = createAction(AppDucksActionTypes.App_DUCKS_TOGGLE_SIDEBAR);
export const getApiVersion = createAction(AppDucksActionTypes.App_DUCKS_GET_API_VERSION,
    dispatch => {
        fetchApiVersion()
            .then(data => {
                let uiVersion = prepareVersion(packageJson.version);
                let apiVersion = prepareVersion(data);
                if (uiVersion !== apiVersion) {
                    dispatch(blockUi({ blocked: true, errorCode: 1000 }));
                }
            });
    }
);

export default function reducer(state, action = {}) {
    state = state || initialState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case AppDucksActionTypes.App_DUCKS_TOGGLE_SIDEBAR: {
            return {
                ...state,
                ui: {
                    ...state.ui,
                    sidebar: {
                        ...state.ui.sidebar,
                        showSidebar: !state.ui.sidebar.showSidebar
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        default:
            return {
                ...state
            };
    }
}
```

*ProductDetailsForm.js*

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { toggleSidebar } from "../../redux/ducks/AppDucks";
import XMLMetaDefinition from "../XMLMetaDefinition";
import MainView from "../layout/main-view/MainView";

export class ProductDetailsForm extends Component {
    state = {
        xmlVersion: '',
        error: ''
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.showSidebar) {
            this.props.toggleSidebar();
        }
    }

    handleXMLMetaDefinitionInput = e => {
        const {value, name} = e.target;
        if (name === "xmlVersion") {
            this.checkSpecialCharacters(value);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <MainView heading='Add meta data definition:'>
                    <XMLMetaDefinition
                        readOnly={false}
                        xmlMetaData={this.state}
                        handleXMLMetaDefinitionInput={
                            this.handleXMLMetaDefinitionInput
                        }
                    />
                </MainView>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
    return {
        toggleSidebar: () => dispatch(toggleSidebar(dispatch))
    };
};

const mapState = state => {
    return {
        showSidebar: state.app_reducer.ui.sidebar.showSidebar
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapState,
    mapDispatch
)(ProductDetailsForm);
```

*ProductDetailsForm.test.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { ProductDetailsForm } from "../ProductDetailsForm";


let clearAll, setProductDetailsFormValue, history, wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
    clearAll = jest.fn();
    history = { push: jest.fn() };
    setProductDetailsFormValue = jest.fn(); 
    wrapper = shallow(
        <ProductDetailsForm
            clearAll={clearAll}
            history={history}
            setProductDetailsFormValue={setProductDetailsFormValue}
        />
    );
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
}); 

test("should call handleMetaDefinitionInput", () => {
    const targetObj = { target: { name: "xmlVersion", value: "!abc?" } };
    const component = wrapper.find("XMLMetaDefinition");
    component.props().handleXMLMetaDefinitionInput(targetObj);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that there's circular dependency, AppDucks->AppService->HttpService->AppDucks . This is what happens when CD is resolved in Jest instead of production environment (likely Webpack). `const` just reveals the problem. The solution is to refactor the code and get rid of CD.

Comment: @EstusFlask  I tried removing the dependency by creating a whole new ErrorDuck.js. But somehow it is with the store, as I am getting the error.

Comment: Please, update the question with new code and error then. Error stack gives a good idea about what's going on.